# AAD pass through authentication requires user provisioning in AAD?

Tags: azure, active-directory

From their docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-pta-how-it-works

*As a pre-requisite for Pass-through Authentication to work, users need to be provisioned into Azure AD from on-premises Active Directory using Azure AD Connect. Pass-through Authentication does not apply to cloud-only users.*

Doesn't this defeat the whole point of pass-through. If users need to be provisioned in AAD (using AD connect), what's the point of pass through? Or is it just that USERNAMES are provisioned and no passwords..?

Very confusing. Please only respond if you have actually implemented this.

Answer (score 2):

We use this at my work. It's better described here: [What is Azure Active Directory Pass-through Authentication?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-pta)

> Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) Pass-through Authentication allows your users to sign in to both on-premises and cloud-based applications using the same passwords. This feature provides your users a better experience - one less password to remember, and reduces IT helpdesk costs because your users are less likely to forget how to sign in. When users sign in using Azure AD, this feature validates users' passwords directly against your on-premises Active Directory.

To use cloud-based services, the account must exist in Azure AD. To use on-premises services, the account must exist on-premises. So everyone's account is actually duplicated between on-premises and Azure AD.

The only purpose of using pass-through authentication is being able to use both cloud and on-premises applications with the same password. Therefore, the password is not stored in Azure AD and Azure AD defers to the on-premises environment to perform the authentication.

Comment: okay, that helps. In effect, it is just identities (minus the password) that is replicated to AAD. Thanks